# Fubini's theorem (interchange of sum and integrals) in case of multivariable function

Tags: integration, summation

Can the Fubini's theorem in case of single variable sequence of functions be readily extended to multivariable sequence of functions?, i.e,

Is it true to say $$\iiint_V\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(u,v,w) \,du\,dv\,dw=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \iiint_Vf_n(u,v,w) \,du\,dv\,dw$$ say for $V=\big\{(u,v,w)| 0\le u<\infty, 0\le v\le 2\pi, 0\le w\le 2\pi\big\}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Fubini's theorem is a statement about when it's okay to interchange integrals, I don't think it says anything about sums.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: If you're careful, you can treat a sum as integration against a counting measure and then you may be able to apply fubini tonelli.

Comment: @ Merlin, would you please elaborate carefulness

Comment: Integral and summation can be interchanged if functions are uniformly continuous along the interval.

Comment: If the series is absolutely convergent, you can define $g_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\vert f_n\vert $, and use MCT to switch the sum and integral. (Fubini comes in when you change the interated integal to one over an integral wrt $\lambda \times \lambda \times \lambda)$.What do you know about the $f_n$? Is $V$ bounded? etc.

Comment: $V$ is not necessarily bounded. However $f_n$ for each $n$ can be bounded.

Comment: One can use dominated convergence theorem to check whether the sum and integral can be interchanged. If $f_n$ is bounded, and if we can find some function with which the value of $f_n$ is dominated, then one can interchange the integral and sum.

Comment: Thank you Shahid. I have a proof now. Thank u all.